# Create Pandas date column from fix starting date and offset days as integer colum

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following one-column Pandas data frame:

```
num_days
--------
9236
9601
9636
10454
```

Here the integers are number of days counted from a constant predefined date:

```
START_DATE = pd.to_datetime('1980-01-01')
```

Now I want to have a column with dates (calculated as `START_DATE` + the respective `num_days`) like this:

```
num_days, date
--------------
9236      '2005-04-15'
9601      '2006-04-15'
9636      '2006-05-20'
10454     '2008-08-15'
```

I have tried this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('1980-01-01') + timedelta(df.num_days)
```

but no success:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime('1980-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df["num_days"], unit="D")
```